# Can Apache handle HTTP request on its own?

Tags: apache, vhosts

I need to return HTTP header value for specific request uri.

I hope there's a same thing like `ErrorDocument` but not `ErrorDocument`.

> ErrorDocument 404 "404 error"
>
> HandleMyRequest /what-is-my-accept-language %{HTTP:Accept-Language}

Of course I know there's nothing like `HandleMyRequest`, I just named it.

The reason of my question is about the **cost**. I can handle it some other whay, but I want to minimize the cost.

Answer (score 0):

it would be less costly in apache theoretically, though if thats all that needs to happen, the difference would probably be immeasurable.

mod_headers (you probably have this module compiled in) can add headers, and they can be whatever you want, so if you want 'HandleMyRequest' as a header, you can have it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html